# Degree symbol breaks URI detector

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

[The revisions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/64781/revisions) for the question [Crossing the Amazon, route 319](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64781/crossing-the-amazon-route-319)

show that the URI detector breaks when it encounters a degree symbol (°) or U+00B9:

[image: Revisions broken link]

The link was copied and pasted from the browser's address field.

Comment: Is this the same on other SE websites?

Comment: I'm not sure if [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) has been superseded or not, but by that standard, technically, URLs are still supposed to be US-ASCII. Support for any other characters is a feature of the client. This URL can be represented as  `https://www.google.com.pe/maps/place/3%C2%B008%2706.5%2522S%2B59%C2%B054%2708.7%2522W/%40-3.1351316%2C-59`

Comment: That should be `https://www.google.com.pe/maps/place/3%C2%B008%2706.5%2522S%2B59%C2%B054%2708.7%2522W/%40-3.1351316%2C-59.9374329%2C14z` rather.

Comment: With maps.google creating that in links, and many browsers supporting it, I think we should code to the "real world."  It's not a "standard" if the majority aren't following it!

Comment: 7320 updates 3986, and suggests supporting anything allowed by HTML 4.01 (which still isn't clear on this).  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7320/?include_text=1

Comment: @WGroleau Thanks, good to know.

Comment: [Posted on Meta.SE.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276686/degree-symbol-breaks-uri-detector)

Comment: I can't quite agree with the idea that we should intentionally create a link that doesn't work with the rationale that the one which DOES work (and is human-readable) is non-standard.

Answer (score 4):

[I re-posted this on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276686/degree-symbol-breaks-uri-detector). The question was shut down as a duplicate of [an unanswered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242571/diamonds-break-the-automatic-hyperlink-parser).

The gist of the highest voted answer is:

> The URL parser is correctly not including the non-encoded diamond character in the URL, because valid URLs simply cannot include them.

There might be a way of arguing for RFC 7320 updating 3986.

Comment: Engineers: the [bureaucrats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo) of making stuff.